# tabularx syntax

Tags: tabularx

First time using tabularx to create tables, my code is below: (which turns out to be very wrong!)

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{\textbf{Description of Regression Variables and Data Sources} \\ This table presents the variable names, definition and data source of the explanatory variables used in Equation~\ref{determinants}. Refer to Table~\ref{tab:sovereignabbreviation} for the abbreviations of the 10 EA sovereigns. Variables 1 to 7 are the local factors and variables 8 to 12 are the regional factors.}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\itshape}lX @{} >{\itshape}lX @{} >{\itshape}lX @{}}\toprule

\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Data Source}} \\ \midrule
1 &        Average probability of default (PoD)          &  Bootstrapped sovereign PoD & Own calculation\\
2 & Standard deviation of PoD            & The standard deviation of the sovereign bootstrapped PoDs computed at each point in time & Own calculation \\
3 & Stock market returns           & Daily stock market returns of the main stock market indices of each sovereign & Datastream \\
4 & Volatility of stock market returns          & Volatility of main stock market returns of each sovereign with a rolling window of 6 months & Datastream\\
5 & Total reserves to debt ratio         & Total reserves excluding gold/government debt & Bloomberg\\
6 & GDP          & Natural log of GDP & Bloomberg \\
7 & Debt to GDP        & Government debt/GDP & Bloomberg \\
8 & Average correlation between changes in CDS Spreads         & Average pairwise correlation with a rolling window of 1 year & Own calculation \\
9 & Standard deviation of changes in CDS spread correlation           & Standard deviation of the average correlation between changes in CDS Spreads computed at each point in time & Own calculation\\
10 & Trade flows          & Sum of imports and exports/GDP & Bloomberg\\
11 & Regional implied volatility          & VSTOXX Index & Datastream\\
12 & Term spread        & Difference between 10-year and the 3-month EA AAA-bond yields & Datastream \\\bottomrule


\end{tabularx}%
\label{variables}
\end{table}%
```

I wish to create a table that looks like this: (Doesn't necessarily need the grid lines)

[image]

How can I do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please always post *complete* documents showing all packages used.

You had fragile commands in the caption, which I avoided by supplying a short caption for the list of tables, and in the tabularx you had specified far more columns than your data used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption[Description of Regression Variables and Data Sources]{Description of Regression Variables and Data Sources\\
This table presents the variable names, definition and data source of the explanatory variables used in Equation~\ref{determinants}. Refer to Table~\ref{tab:sovereignabbreviation} for the abbreviations of the 10 EA sovereigns. Variables 1 to 7 are the local factors and variables 8 to 12 are the regional factors.}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l>{\raggedright}X>{\raggedright}Xl@{}}\toprule

\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Data Source}} \\ \midrule
1 &        Average probability of default (PoD)          &  Bootstrapped sovereign PoD & Own calculation\\
2 & Standard deviation of PoD            & The standard deviation of the sovereign bootstrapped PoDs computed at each point in time & Own calculation \\
3 & Stock market returns           & Daily stock market returns of the main stock market indices of each sovereign & Datastream \\
4 & Volatility of stock market returns          & Volatility of main stock market returns of each sovereign with a rolling window of 6 months & Datastream\\
5 & Total reserves to debt ratio         & Total reserves excluding gold/government debt & Bloomberg\\
6 & GDP          & Natural log of GDP & Bloomberg \\
7 & Debt to GDP        & Government debt/GDP & Bloomberg \\
8 & Average correlation between changes in CDS Spreads         & Average pairwise correlation with a rolling window of 1 year & Own calculation \\
9 & Standard deviation of changes in CDS spread correlation           & Standard deviation of the average correlation between changes in CDS Spreads computed at each point in time & Own calculation\\
10 & Trade flows          & Sum of imports and exports/GDP & Bloomberg\\
11 & Regional implied volatility          & VSTOXX Index & Datastream\\
12 & Term spread        & Difference between 10-year and the 3-month EA AAA-bond yields & Datastream \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\label{variables}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on @{}l>{\raggedright}X>{\raggedright}Xl@{} ? I'm not sure how to add columns in tabularx environment.

Comment: The only additional change I'd suggest is to load the `ragged2e` package and to use `>{\RaggedRight}X` as the specifier for the two middle columns. This will allow hyphenation of words to be performed.

Comment: @TrueTears tabularx syntax is exactly the same as (array package) `tabular` syntax with the addtion of `X` which is `p{some length` so you have 4 columns `lXXl` but you want the two `X` columns to be ragged not justified so `>{\raggedright}X` or `>{\RaggedRight}X` as suggested in the comments where `\RaggedRight` is a perhaps better raggedright macro than the standard one.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thanks, how about @{} ? What is that used for?

Answer (score 3):

Remarks for the example below:

- Package `raggedright` provides `\RaggedRight` that is similar to `\raggedright`, but allows hyphenation to get a smoother right margin, especially for narrow columns.
- `>{\itspape}lX`: Your example image does not contain italics. Also this are *two* columns, a left-aligned column and an extensible column that allows several lines. The example images contains one ragged-right column instead.
- With some trickery via `\hsize` the width of the `X`-columns can be adjusted, the column "Description" contains more text, thus I have made the column wider.
  See the examples in the documentation of `tabularx`.
- `l` seems to be enough for the third column.
- Also I have added some indentation of the followup lines in the table cells. Perhaps it makes the tabular rows more clear and easier to read.
- The caption I have formatted via package `caption`. Instead of the caption text I have made the caption label bold, because I think it is more common, if something is made bold in the caption. Your version would be the commented line above. Also both can be made bold (combine both options `labelfont` and `textfont`).
- Since one-line captions are centered by default, I have added option `singlelinecheck`.
- IMHO the legend does not belong to the caption, therefore I have moved the explanation text outside the caption. Otherwise the optional argument of `\caption` should be used to prevent that the legend appears in the list of tables.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand*{\xformat}{%
  \RaggedRight
  \setlength{\hangindent}{1em}%
  \hangafter=1\relax
}

%\captionsetup{textfont+=bf, singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup{labelfont+=bf, singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Description of Regression Variables and Data Sources}

This table presents the variable names, definition and data source of the
explanatory variables used in Equation~\ref{determinants}.  Refer to
Table~\ref{tab:sovereignabbreviation} for the abbreviations of the 10 EA
sovereigns.  Variables 1 to 7 are the local factors and variables 8 to 12
are the regional factors.

\medskip
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}%
  {r >{\xformat\hsize=.75\hsize}X >{\xformat\hsize=1.25\hsize}X l}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Data Source}} \\
\midrule
1 &        Average probability of default (PoD)          &  Bootstrapped sovereign PoD & Own calculation\\
2 & Standard deviation of PoD            & The standard deviation of the sovereign bootstrapped PoDs computed at each point in time & Own calculation \\
3 & Stock market returns           & Daily stock market returns of the main stock market indices of each sovereign & Datastream \\
4 & Volatility of stock market returns          & Volatility of main stock market returns of each sovereign with a rolling window of 6 months & Datastream\\
5 & Total reserves to debt ratio         & Total reserves excluding gold/government debt & Bloomberg\\
6 & GDP          & Natural log of GDP & Bloomberg \\
7 & Debt to GDP        & Government debt/GDP & Bloomberg \\
8 & Average correlation between changes in CDS Spreads         & Average pairwise correlation with a rolling window of 1 year & Own calculation \\
9 & Standard deviation of changes in CDS spread correlation           & Standard deviation of the average correlation between changes in CDS Spreads computed at each point in time & Own calculation\\
10 & Trade flows          & Sum of imports and exports/GDP & Bloomberg\\
11 & Regional implied volatility          & VSTOXX Index & Datastream\\
12 & Term spread        & Difference between 10-year and the 3-month EA AAA-bond yields & Datastream \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\label{variables}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

```
[...]
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
[...]

\begingroup
\noindent\tabcolsep=3pt
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}r>{\RaggedRight}X>{\RaggedRight}Xl @{}}\toprule
[...]
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
[...]
```